# Macro that copies from one tab and pastes in a different tab based on a match of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to expand upon a worksheet and require assistance.

Currently I have the following macro set up to copy from one sheet range and paste to another sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Set Rng1 = Range("D12:G253")
Set Rng2 = Range("D12:G253")
Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value


Dim xlws1 As Worksheet
Dim xlws2 As Worksheet

Set xlws1 = Worksheets("Data")
Set Rng1 = xlws1.Range("d12:g253")

Set xlws2 = Worksheets("Final")
Set Rng2 = xlws2.Range("D12:g253")
Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value
```

However, now I would like the data pasted to be dynamic and not always land in "D12:G253" but instead find the four columns that correspond to the value in either the seventh or eight row.  I have descriptions set up in the first three columns that I will stay and not need to be copied and I have headers in the first 11 rows that will not need to change either.

I've tried following these posts [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316086/macro-to-copy-range-and-paste-based-on-cell-value#) [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218923/macro-with-match-or-if-then-copy-into-a-new-tab) but cannot follow completely due to my lack of coding knowledge.

Please help me so I can expand.

[image: Screenshot of example worksheet]

Comment: I don't think I understand what this means: "find the four columns that correspond to the value in either the seventh or eight row".

Comment: Basically, rows 1 through 8 will have the same four column header that will repeat through the spreadsheet.  I've included a screenshot of an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdEZF.png

In this example, I want the macro to reference the value that would be in row 8 then post in the four columns under that refence (such as D through G, I through L, etc).

Comment: Try also to give an example of final output... still to unclear :(

Comment: I am not allowed to embed pictures in my posts yet but here are links to the inputs and the outputs.  Note that the input was entered on the first tab (data), the macro was run, and based on the text on line 8 it was pasted either under "Example" or "Example 2".

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZIca.png

  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ1zS.png

  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAj8b.png

  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuDif.png